# Associate a Readable User Dropdown in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I guess not much help [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4344). When you are trying to associate a user from a dropdown list, and imagine if you have 1000000 users, you would see the user instance. I need it to show the actual user's email address.

[image]

**app/models/user.rb:**

```
has_one :company
```

**app/models/company.rb:**

```
belongs_to :user
```

[The link I was given](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/a252cebb4e6b4939775df2ef6920f16bec38f884/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.md#defining-columns) has nothing to do with the dropdown's value.

Have I setup my rails association incorrectly? Funny thing was, using rails admin I had no issue in this department as I could associate a company when creating a user but not so with active admin.

All I want is when I select the User dropdown, as in picture, I'd see a list of user email addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tim](https://github.com/timoschilling) was correct all this time. I needed to create a function in the User model.

app/models/user.rb:

```
def display_name
 email
end
```

Comment: 1) it's method, not a function. 2) you do not need `return`. 3) you do not need `self`.

Comment: I'm switching between js and ruby ;) Yes, I never needed `return` nor `self`